# Why does my own dupe CV on my own question not immediately close it?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

If I vote to close my own Q as dupe, it has no effect other than casting a dupe vote.

But if I then refresh the page, I see that note on top of it asking whether that other question solved my problem.

Clicking on "Yes" there finally lets the Community user close it.

An example where this happened on Ask Ubuntu is [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/789355/367990).

Why doesn't my first own dupe close vote immediately close my own question instead?